# How can I setup two or multiple reverse zone for one IP with bind9?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, authoritative

When I try to define reverse zone with same IP the as reverse zone `named-checkconf` throws:

```
$ named-checkconf named.conf.cust_zone
named.conf:63: zone '70.231.168.192.in-addr.arpa': already exists previous definition: named.conf:52
```

My config file.

```
...
// zone for the 1st domain

zone "domain_1.com"{
    type master;    
    file "file"
}

// reverse zone for 1st domain 

zone "70.231.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "file";                                                                                                                                                                   }

// zone for the 2nd domain

zone "domain_2.com"{
    type master;    
    file "file"
}

// reverse zone for 2nd domain 

zone "70.231.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "file";
}
...
```

It works when I change one of the reverse zone name. But I am not sure would it work ?

So, is there are any way to configure two reverse zone for one IP ?

Comment: Reverse zones are exacly like forward zones. A zone is a zone, it can't appear twice. You have to combine all content into one. And normally the zone would be for part of the tree, not just the final record. AKA your zone should probably be more for `168.192.in-addr.arpa.`

Comment: Yes I know that, but if I have multiple zones and I've just one IP then what should I do ?

Comment: No you don't have multiple zones. Each node in the tree is unique, you can't have multiple time the same zone, that is meaningless (except if you implement split view). Your unique IP has one (or more, but mostly useless) `PTR` records, so you just define the zone needed to hold them. Also are you 100% sure you even need a reverse zone. This is almost never needed in fact, `PTR` records have usefulness only for mail configurations basically.

Comment: Basically I want setup two mail server in the same host. That's why I want to configure multiple zones. 

e.g: This is the first time I am trying to configure mail server. Please pardon my mistakes.

Comment: You have one zone, and in it one IP address (in reverse) with two `PTR` records for it, that is all. However you can not guarantee that all clients will take into account properly two `PTR` records. So you may want to smart small in order to better understand both DNS and email hosting, by just doing one mail server, and when you are 100% good with it, then you can think about the next steps.

Comment: Thank you for kind advice.

Comment: i flagged this question sue its offtopic imho.One IP, One PTR. you just duplicate the entry for the same ip. PTR is ip bound and not domain based to be easy said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have listed the same `zone` twice in `named.conf`. Each `zone` can only appear once here.

Your comments seem to indicate that you think these are different zones, but they are exactly the same zone.

Remove the duplicate entry from `named.conf`.